# Yii2 how to add price range filter in search model

Tags: php, search, filter, yii

I have created a search model in yii2.I want to add a price starting and price ending textfields and filter condition in it.Now the filter options given below

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'city_id' => $this->city_id,
            'price' => $this->price, <====Here i want to add price range
            'age_id' => $this->age_id,
            'usage_id' => $this->usage_id,
            'condition_id' => $this->condition_id,
            'seller_type_id' => $this->seller_type_id,
            'warranty_id' => $this->warranty_id,
            'flag' => $this->flag,
        ]);
```

How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

I just done like this

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['between','price',$this->price_start,$this->price_end])
```